# Which optics books should I use to prepare for IIT jam physics?

Tags: optics, resource-recommendations, education

Some people suggest using Ghatak, but I feel it is quite advanced. I'd prefer a book which is useful for problem solving, especially within the context of the IIT Jam Physics. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Potential duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/43133/good-books-about-waves-and-optics/43136#43136, https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/21288/where-is-a-good-place-to-learn-classical-optics-for-high-school-competitions, and https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/15686/extra-help-in-optics.

Answer (score 1):

The classic recommendation I always hear for optics is [Optics, by Hecht](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0805385665) - it's rec'd for instance [on Baez's collaborative list](https://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/physics/Administrivia/booklist.html#optics), and a site recommending books to study for IIT Jam [also recommends it](https://www.shiksha.com/science/articles/best-books-for-iit-jam-physics-prep-2021-blogId-23711). Of course, not all textbooks suit everyone - here are some alternatives and potential supplemental references:

- [Introduction to Modern Optics by Fowles](http://www.fulviofrisone.com/attachments/article/404/Introduction%20to%20Modern%20Optics.pdf) - found in a thread ranting about why the OP hated Hecht, so if you don't like Hecht this might be a good alternative. It's also free online at the link, and looks to be a Dover publication, which are generally pretty good.
- [Physics of Light and Optics](https://optics.byu.edu/docs/opticsBook.pdf), also online for free, developed by professors at BYU. This one seems to have a lot of problems and be slightly less...dense, perhaps? But your mileage may vary.
- There's also several sets of lecture notes that basically act as textbooks available online free, see [here](https://webspace.science.uu.nl/%7Egadda001/goodtheorist/files/louro_optics.pdf) and [here](http://atomoptics-nas.uoregon.edu/%7Edsteck/teaching/optics/). Might be useful as references/secondary explanations of confusing concepts, but don't have problems.
- Hecht also apparently wrote a Schaum's outline on optics that may have more problems to solve and might be a more introductory overview.

See also the posts I commented as potential duplicates.